# NLog extensibility - How to add custom field using ExtendValues?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nlog, extensibility, logz.io

I try to add some custom fields to NLog using [extensibility](https://github.com/logzio/logzio-dotnet/blob/master/docs/nlog.md#extensibility).

Part of my `nlog.config` file looks like that : (simplified for exhibit)

```
<nlog>
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="Logzio.DotNet.NLog"/>
    </extensions>

    <variable name="currentUser" value="test" />

    <targets async="true">
        <target name="logzio" type="Logzio" token="myToken">
          <contextproperty name="currentUser" layout="${currentUser}" />
        </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logzio" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

In every controller, I have something like that (I'm using ASP.NET MVC5)

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Then I send my logs to logzio using

```
logger.Fatal("Something bad happens");
```

Right now, `currentUser` always have the value `test`, which is logical.

However, despite of the [documentation](https://github.com/logzio/logzio-dotnet/blob/master/docs/nlog.md#extensibility), I don't understand how to dynamically change `currentUser` value by the ID of my current logged user.

Should I create a sort of factory ? (if yes, how ? I'm not at ease with factories)
Should I change my `logger` variable ? If so, how ?

A piece of code would be extremly welcome.

Thank you for pointing my out where I'm wrong

**EDIT**

After @Rolf's answer, I've created this custom layout renderer

```
[LayoutRenderer("custom-layout")]
public class CustomLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    public string IdUser { get; set; }


    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        logEvent.Properties.Add("currentUser", "HowToPassCustomDataHere?");
        builder.Append("test from custom-layout");
    }
}
```

and I changed the nlog.config accordingly, adding

```
layout="${message} ${custom-layout}"
```

to my `<target>`

However, I still don't understand how to pass custom value to `currentUser`. In logz.io, I have "HowToPassCustomDataHere?" as a value of `currentUser`.

(BTW, `${aspnet-user-identity}` is great and works fine ; however I'd like to understand how to pass a custom value to my layout renderer. In my case, something like `${aspnet-user-id}`)

Comment: You should not modify the LogEventInfo.Properties in the LayoutRenderer. The LayoutRenderer should only write the wanted context-info to the StringBuilder.

Comment: The idea is that you initialize the LayoutRenderer to be able to capture the username from somewhere. For ASP.NET then one can use global HttpContext. Which all of these are doing: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/tree/master/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/LayoutRenderers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of these NLog layoutrenderers to acquire the current username:

- `${aspnet-user-identity}` [Wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetUserIdentity-layout-renderer)
- `${windows-identity}` [Wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetUserIdentity-layout-renderer)

You can also create your own custom NLog LayoutRenderer: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer

Example of how to provide it as currentUser:

```
    <target name="logzio" type="Logzio" token="myToken">
      <contextproperty name="currentUser" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
    </target>
```

Comment: +1 for `${aspnet-user-identity}`, that's great and (almost) what I want. However, I still have an issue with LayoutRenderer, could you please take a look to my edit ?

Comment: Think you need to study NLog Layout Renderers a little more. I don't know what you intend to return in `${aspnet-user-id}` Maybe look at the source-code for the existing layout-renderers to get inspiration for your own. More here https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetRequest-layout-renderer

Comment: Maybe create new question for how to customize the output from `${aspnet-user-identity}` to be just like you want.

Comment: @user2687153 Have now update the answer with example of how to pass the output from `${aspnet-user-identity}` as `currentUser`-property.